# Using gradient ascent for image segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, crf

I am working with image segmentation using saliency maps via gradient ascent.
Here is an image of the process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k30j.jpg

I have a trained model that can accurately predict my classes. This model is then used to compute a gradient of an input picture with gradient ascent wrt loss. To me, the gradient produced here is a representation of what the model is focusing on in prediction.

I run a quantile filter to pick out the the gradient values (pixels) that are most related to the class, then produce a binary mask from this. This works well, but find that the map could be more accurate and tighter around the class within the image. I read about Conditional Random Fields as a mechanism to generate more accurate and smooth segmentation results and am attempting to implement this, but feel as if I don't have a full understanding of the gradient produced here.

My question is: what exactly does the gradient represent in this case? My guess is that these values are essentially pixel level predictions/pixel labels. Is this equivalent to unary potentials?

Answer (score 0):

There is an end-to-end training method combying a neural network with a CRF that does exactly what you want it to do. The paper is this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10229.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions, based on your example images. The difference between pixel labels and potentials is very good described here in this tutorial: [Demo Train](http://research.project-10.de/dgmdoc/a00984.html)

1. The quantile filter has overfilling at the object. I suspect that you normalize the image values to the range [0..255] and have this "waves effect" in the place of the object of interest. If you scale first the image values by some factor less than one (e.g. 0,5 or 0,1) than you could normalize them into the range [0..255] properly and using thresholding extract more accurate class region.
2. You can try advanced pairwise potentials for your CRF. For example contrast-sensitive potentials, or even [concatenated edge potentials](http://research.project-10.de/dgmdoc/a00804.html). They may help to refine the class-object more accurately. 
   In addition, it is worth trying to add more features for training unary potentials. HOG, or Sparse Coding features may help.